# How to construct Map with values in application.yml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

How to construct map with values in application.yml file, I was able to create a list of Objects but I'm looking for how can I construct Map

Here is my application.ymal file

```
parentkey:
  child:
    - key1: 123
      key2:
        subkey: value1
      key3:
        subkey1: value2
        subkey3: value3
      key4:
        subkey4: value4
    - key1: 123
      key2:
        subkey: value5
      key3:
        subkey1: value6
        subkey3: value7
      key4:
        subkey4: value8
```

and I created my like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("parentkey")
public class ConfigurationTest {
 private List<Configuration> child;
}
```

now in my ConfigurationTest class can I get Map with key as value of key1 and value as Object contains key2 to ke4

if yes, how Can I construct my application.ymal file

Comment: The question is more subtle than it first appears. The `child` node contains keys that have different types of structure. Can you show a class or classes that represents the structure you desire?

Answer (score 2):

The map in yml can be created like this

```
parentkey:
 child:
   123:
    key2:
     subkey: value1
    key3:
     subkey1: value2
     subkey3: value3
    key4:
     subkey4: value4
   234:
    key2:
     subkey: value5
    key3:
     subkey1: value6
     subkey3: value7
    key4:
     subkey4: value8
```

This can be read the same way Map<String, Object> child where keys will be 123 and 234.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can translate YAML into a variety of object types, including user-defined classes as well as things like `List<>` and `Map<>`. It is also recursive; it can translate nested objects into other types.

Knowing that, you can define an `@ConfigurationProperties` class that contains a `Map<>` and Spring will automatically create the objects to populate your map as long as it can figure out how to translate the key and value types.

For example, using a properties class like this:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "parentkey")
public class MyConfigProps {
    private Map<String, String> children;

    // getters and setters
}
```

This YAML will populate an instance of that class:

```yaml
parentkey:
  children:
    - key1: 123
    - key2: abc
```

---

In the question it looks like the children nodes are not all of the same type; some are simple integer or string values, some have nested children themselves. So you'll have to tweak my example to match the actual structure you need to support. But since Spring can translate arbitrarily nested structures/objects, almost anything is possible.